# NameError: name "" not defined when it comes to ordinary variables

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I would like to say first that I am a bit new to using Jupyter Notebook. I am having an issue where one of my variables isn't defined even though I've ran everything above the cell that calls/utilizes the variable. The variable in question is 'matches'. The first two screenshots are the cells above the problem cells and their respective outputs (disregard the outputs, these cells work fine). The last screenshot is where the error occurs.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6TtU.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD5Oz.png)

[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKDN9.png)

Comment: These no way from what you've shared to be sure '`matches`' is actually defined. It could have errored out later. You just shared the top of the cell running. Please don't share code this way. You can share nbviewer static views of notebooks [like this](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/b1b6f9e4cdbb20d331705dbec8c91c0a), by posting them as gists at GIthub, like [this one](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/b1b6f9e4cdbb20d331705dbec8c91c0a) and then pointing [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/) at it using the form (or learning the pattern). Plus you would post a specific title about prody.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your code worked for me when I made `struct1 = parsePDB("6vxx")` and `struct2 = parsePDB("6vxx")` and then ran your `matches` line. Then I put `matches` on the next cell alone, I could see results. I didn't work beyond that yet.